# connection pool exception on keycloak when using SPI

Tags: oracle, keycloak, connection-pool

We are randomly receiving a connection error from a connection pool defined on wildfly which is serving keycloak 15.1.1

the oracle driver is oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver 19.13

It happens randomly, we have also validation enabled on the connection pool to validate the connections on acquire.

the error/warning

```
    2023-08-09 16:59:58,338 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (default task-1) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@709eb21[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@6a62181c connection handles=1 lastReturned=1691589576361 lastValidated=1691589576361 lastCheckedOut=1691589595369 trackByTx=true pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@71bd5f4c mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@1ddb7d86[pool=projectDS] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@6bb409dd[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@6a62181c pad=false overrideRmValue=false productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/projectDB] txSync=TransactionSynchronization@1054125327{tx=Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a8291a:-5a55d2c4:64d0ec2c:28168 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider) wasTrackByTx=true enlisted=true cancel=false}]: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read interrupted
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:821)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at com.project.repository.projectUserRepository.getUserByUsername(projectUserRepository.java:67)
    at com.project.keycloak.spi.storage.exchange.projectExchangeUserStorageProvider.getUserByUsername(projectExchangeUserStorageProvider.java:64)
    at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.lambda$getUserByUsername$12(UserStorageManager.java:298)
    at org.keycloak.utils.ServicesUtils.lambda$timeBoundOne$1(ServicesUtils.java:83)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:395)
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getUserByUsername(UserStorageManager.java:298)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserByUsername(UserCacheSession.java:259)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.findUserByNameOrEmail(KeycloakModelUtils.java:225)
    at com.project.keycloak.spi.authenticator.projectValidateUsername.authenticate(projectValidateUsername.java:50)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:446)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:253)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:990)
    at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.resourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(TokenEndpoint.java:663)
    at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor463.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:110)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
    at org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Socket read interrupted
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.handleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:258)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:180)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:560)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:263)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:195)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:137)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:110)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:791)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:449)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:410)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807)
    ... 107 more

2023-08-09 16:59:58,341 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (default task-1) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@709eb21[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@6a62181c connection handles=0 lastReturned=1691589576361 lastValidated=1691589576361 lastCheckedOut=1691589595369 trackByTx=true pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@71bd5f4c mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@1ddb7d86[pool=projectDS] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@6bb409dd[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@6a62181c pad=false overrideRmValue=false productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/projectDB] txSync=TransactionSynchronization@1054125327{tx=Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a8291a:-5a55d2c4:64d0ec2c:28168 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider) wasTrackByTx=true enlisted=true cancel=true}]: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException: XAErr (-7): Resource manager is unavailable. ORA-17008 SQLErr (0)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1114)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.end(OracleXAResource.java:468)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.end(XAManagedConnection.java:299)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.end(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperStatImpl.end(XAResourceWrapperStatImpl.java:96)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.delistResource(TransactionImple.java:912)
    at org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.delistResource(LocalTransaction.java:185)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.haltCatchFire(TxConnectionListener.java:768)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.AbstractConnectionListener.connectionErrorOccurred(AbstractConnectionListener.java:470)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.broadcastConnectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:676)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.connectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:627)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkException(WrappedConnection.java:2043)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkException(WrappedStatement.java:1436)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:509)
    at com.project.repository.projectUserRepository.getUserByUsername(projectUserRepository.java:67)
    at com.project.keycloak.spi.storage.exchange.projectExchangeUserStorageProvider.getUserByUsername(projectExchangeUserStorageProvider.java:64)
    at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.lambda$getUserByUsername$12(UserStorageManager.java:298)
    at org.keycloak.utils.ServicesUtils.lambda$timeBoundOne$1(ServicesUtils.java:83)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:395)
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getUserByUsername(UserStorageManager.java:298)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserByUsername(UserCacheSession.java:259)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.findUserByNameOrEmail(KeycloakModelUtils.java:225)
    at com.project.keycloak.spi.authenticator.projectValidateUsername.authenticate(projectValidateUsername.java:50)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:446)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:253)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:990)
    at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.resourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(TokenEndpoint.java:663)
    at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor463.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:110)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
    at org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:3550)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource.doEnd(T4CXAResource.java:386)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.end(OracleXAResource.java:463)
    ... 112 more

2023-08-09 16:59:58,343 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) ARJUNA016056: TransactionImple.delistResource - caught exception during delist : XAException.XAER_RMFAIL: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException: XAErr (-7): Resource manager is unavailable. ORA-17008 SQLErr (0)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1114)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.end(OracleXAResource.java:468)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.end(XAManagedConnection.java:299)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.end(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperStatImpl.end(XAResourceWrapperStatImpl.java:96)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.delistResource(TransactionImple.java:912)
    at org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.delistResource(LocalTransaction.java:185)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.haltCatchFire(TxConnectionListener.java:768)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.AbstractConnectionListener.connectionErrorOccurred(AbstractConnectionListener.java:470)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.broadcastConnectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:676)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.end(XAManagedConnection.java:311)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.end(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperStatImpl.end(XAResourceWrapperStatImpl.java:96)
    at
```